# Is there any performance difference in ES modules vs Common JS modules in NodeJS servers?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, es6-modules, commonjs

Is there any performance advantage or disadvantage of using ES modules over CommonJS modules in a nodejs backend project? I'm asking this because I see a lot of people using CJS still even though newer versions of NodeJS support ES modules fully.

Comment: If there is a performance difference it's likely negligible compared to everything else that's going on (e.g. I/O).

Comment: The performance of the app is the same, but when starting node index.mjs and node index.cjs the later seems faster to kick in. maybe it is just my machine.

Comment: The only real difference is load time - which happens only once every time you (re)start your server. It would be a difference between 10's of millisecond to 100's of milliseconds. Node does not have 1+ minute start-up times like other languages (hi Java). So it would be like the difference of starting up your server in 0.1 second and 0.2 second - a measurable difference for sure but practically no significant difference

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An import statement can reference an ES module or a CommonJS module. import statements are permitted only in ES modules, but dynamic import() expressions are supported in CommonJS for loading ES modules.

When importing CommonJS modules, the `module.exports` object is provided as the default export. Named exports may be available, provided by static analysis as a convenience for better ecosystem compatibility.

The major difference in CommonJS and ES module is of synchronous and asynchronous nature, which might affect performance:

- CommonJS modules are synchronous, which isn't an issue in the case of small module execution. However it can delay execution for larger modules.
- Loading and parsing of ES modules is asynchronous.

Comment: If using one of the items within an ES module, I assume it has handling to where it will always ensure it's loaded before an functions within it are called?

Answer (score 0):

I do have a module which does have nested imports/exports. About 100 of them from about 15 files. The package is written with ESM and Commonjs support is done with Babel. I did a very simple test where I import only the basic class from my package and console it.

When importing the basic class using commonjs it is faster then using ESM.
the difference is small but visible.

```bash
?> time node index.cjs
> 0.15
?> time node index.mjs
> 0.25
```

It might be just my npm package, but in this case it is pretty consistent. Running on node 20.